# Best Approach To Handle Multiple Select Statements In A Single Trip To The Database

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am thinking a transaction would help me in the following example but I could be wrong. What I am attempting to avoid is making 3 different calls to the database if I dont have too in the following scenerio..

I want to do the following:

1. select name, address from employee
2. select state from states
3. select error from errorTable

In this case I have to call several different selects to get data. What is the best way to approach this scenerio to return all the data I want to read minimizing several calls to the database?

Note: No tables have a relationship between them.

Comment: What's the relationship, if any, between the records you're fetching? Can you edit some schema information into the question?

Comment: no relationship between these tables. That is where my confusion on how to handle this scenerio stems

Comment: If you are calling these three queries many multiples of times, then perhaps look at prepared statements to minimise the overhead of repeated queries.  If you only call these once each, this feels like a case of optimising in the wrong place.  Have you quantified the overhead of three queries and established that it really is a cause of issues?

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to run them in single iteration? There is no relation b/w the tables and hence can't be logically grouped.

Comment: What's your front end?  ADO that supports multiple result sets?  SSMS?  Something else? Also, going along with @MatBailie aren't states pretty static and something you would want to cache ?

Comment: I need to crosswalk data. So data comes in as "123" I need to look at a certain table and get the translation, like our system for name "123" means "ABC". There are many refereance tables like this that are Not related

Comment: ... wait ... what?! How isn't that related data?

Comment: One table holds employee codes, another table holds state codes, etc.. in the state code table fields would be InState, Description, TransState and in the employee code table the schema would be SourceEmCode, Description, TransEmCode..This is just an example but they are not releated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no relation between the tables you could do a kind of

```
Select [Your selected columns]
From (select * from table1 where [conditon for table1]) t1
Inner join (select * from table2 where [condition for table2]) t2 on 1=1 
Inner join (select * from table3 where [condition for table3]) t3 on 1=1
```

This makes one trip to the database.

Comment: And if query 1 returns 10 records, query 2 returns 20 records and query 3 returns 30 records, then you'll get 6000 records back.  That's not what I'd call optimisation.

Comment: @MatBailie good point. I would work fine for one row per table. And It's bad optimization for multiple rows in multiple tables.

Comment: Why can't you return multiple sets from sql server and capture them in a data reader?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `reader.NextResult()` to iterate through result sets. An example borrowed from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/306722/Executing-multiple-SQL-statements-as-one-against-S#pre5):

```
connection.Open();
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(); // a multi-select query
while (loopResult) {
   stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   while (dataReader.Read()) {
      stringBuilder.AppendLine(dataReader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
   }
   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString(), "Data from the result set");
   loopResult = dataReader.NextResult();
}
```

But, I'm not sure what the rationale is for grouping queries for unrelated data. It'll likely make your project harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: @I don't see if the OP has mentioned that he is using .NET. So, why this solution.

Comment: @Rahul It's tagged with sql-server ... I made an assumption.

Comment: yes tagged as sqlserver and not .NET. Moreover, OP asking for TSQL solution/suggestion and .NET.

Comment: @Rahul Yeah. Also with `t-sql`. Generally when someone's running `t-sql` against `sql-server` they're using .NET. I could certainly be wrong ... It's a reasonable assumption though, isn't it?

Comment: Im using .Net, its fine assuption

Comment: @NickLaMarca if you are running .NET then tag it and how is this not the best answer.   Per the comment the accepted answer will return multiple rows.   svidgen since the tables return different data can't use a single loop.

Comment: I need to crosswalk data. So data comes in as "123" I need to look at a certain table and get the translation, like our system for name "123" means "ABC". There are many refereance tables like this that are Not related

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a stored procedure.

Comment: what if thats not an option? Also can you show me a quick sample of a sp with these sample selects?

Comment: If a sp is not an option, then you might want to think about using a `union` to couple a few select statements together.  For example:  select column1,column2 ,column3 from table1 union select column1,column2 ,column3 from table2

The only caveat to this is that the number of columns must be the same for all queries.

Comment: Errr, and the same data types.  Errr, and you need a way to identify which row is from which query.  Errr, and you may have network traffic overhead due to communicating that additional column.  Errr, and additional traffic communicating NULLs where columns exist in one record set but not others.  Errr, and confusion caused by potentially forcing data into fields with the same type but the wrong name.  Yeah,just the one caveat...

Answer (score 0):

You could try select query with JOIN table if there is relationship between them

Comment: no tables have a relationship between them

Comment: Join is not a solution since most probably he is trying to query different tables

Comment: @MillerKoijam - That's simply a cartesian product.  Are you ***really*** suggesting a CROSS JOIN of three different record sets???

Comment: Probably, SP with multiple select query  is the only option left.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using ASP.Net 4.0...

You can "chain" the queries together by doing something like this:

```
select name, address from employee;select state from states;select error from errorTable;
```

And then fill a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
string sql = "...";
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
SqlDataAdapter adpr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adpr.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: yea I thought so too the queries will run seperatly not a single call

Comment: It is my understanding that will make 1 call to the db and return the 3 tables/results...

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a stored procedure, then you have on option: Execute multiple `select` statements in a single batch. This 'batch' is processed as a single entity by SQL Server, returning multiple result sets. Once you have that, you can

1. Read it via a SqlDataReader, thus:

   ```
   using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using ( SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand() )
   {

     cmd.CommandText = " select * from foo"
                     + " select * from bar"
                     + " select * from baz"
                     + " select * from bat"
                     ;
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; ;

     using ( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
     {
       int n = 0 ;

       do
       {

         Console.WriteLine( "Result set #{0}", ++n ) ;
         int rows = 0 ;
         while ( reader.Read() )
         {
           ++rows ;
           for ( int i = 0 ; i < reader.FieldCount ; ++i )
           {
             object o1 = reader[i] ; // get object by ordinal column number
             string columnName = reader.GetName(i) ;
             object o2 = reader[columnName];
           }
         }
         Console.WriteLine("  {0} rows", rows ) ;

       } while ( reader.NextResult() ) ;
     }
   ```
2. Read it via a `SqlDataAdapter`, thus:

   ```
   DataSet results = new DataSet() ;

   using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using ( SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand() )
   using ( SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) )
   {
     cmd.CommandText = " select * from foo"
                     + " select * from bar"
                     + " select * from baz"
                     + " select * from bat"
                     ;
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; ;

     connection.Open() ;
     int rowcount = adapter.Fill(results) ;
     connection.Close() ;

   }

   Process(results) ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't return multiple sets from sql server.

```
select name, address from employee;
select state from states;
select error from errorTable;
```

User a sql reader and getting the .NextResult will go to the next dataset.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-multiple-resultsets.htm